# Zurb Ink Responsive HTML email: increase line height on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, email, zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

Using Zurb Ink ( http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs.html )

I have created a responsive layout for my email. For the mobile devices, particularly iPhones, I've been using `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 150%;` to increase the font size for ONLY mobile devices. However, the `line-height` does not adjust, and I'm left with bigger font sizes, as I wanted, but some vertical overlap, since the bigger fonts still have smaller line heights.

I tried to add this in my `style` tags:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .body {
    font-size: 16px !important; line-height: 38px;
  }
}
```

And then ran it through the zurb inliner ( http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html )

But to no avail. Anyone have any idea how to increase line-heights for HTML emails in mobile only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `line-height` is likely defined in `px`. Change the `line-height` statements to use `em` units.

For example, if you previously had a `font-size` of `16px` and a `line-height` of `20px`, you could change `line-height` to `line-height: 1.25em`. This would maintain the same line height as before, but scale with font size when you change it on mobile.

Comment: Awesome, was really starting to look like I wouldn't be able to find a solution to this issue, but this works great.